# How eliminate the use of for loops using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I was wondering if it is always possible to avoid using for loops for actions to dataframes. For example, let's assume we have the following dataframe named df(1000,5)

```
step 1   step 2   step 3    step 4   step 5
300       200      500       300      3000  
400       700      1500      2000     2100 
3000      1500     500       5000     4000 
...        ...        ...    ...       ...
```

and the following series max_cash(1000,1)

```
Max Cash
1500
3000
5000
```

We also have a function named future_cash() that gives us the cash to be added in the next step. However, if the money is more or equal than the maximum cash then the value should not be added. Instead we should place a 0
So let's say every time we add 1000. The final outcome should be

```
step 1   step 2   step 3     step 4  step 5
1300      1200       0       1300      0  
1400      1700       2500    0         0 
4000      2500       3500    0         0 
...        ...        ...    ...       ...
```

The way I solved it is the following:

```
# This is the main let's say part where I loop over the columns of my dataframe
for i in range (0,5):
    deposit = future_cash()
    df.iloc[:, i] = fix_values_for_steps (df.iloc[:, i],max_cash, deposit)

# This is a function I created so I can filter the values and either add the money or place a 0
def fix_values_for_steps(col_from_df: pd.Series, maximum_cash: pd.Series, money:int) -> pd.Series:
    for i in range(len(df)):   
        if df['Maximum Cash'].iloc[i]>=  col_from_df.iloc[i]+money:
              col_from_df.iloc[i] col_from_df.iloc[i]+money   
        else
              col_from_df.iloc[i] = 0
```

Now my question is how can I optimise my code? I think that instead of using the double loop I could do it with 1 loop but using the whole column but I am not sure how to do that

Comment: You could initialize a numpy array for each column and do operations on numpy arrays. Its much faster

Comment: Hello. You mean just do 1 loop and use a column in each iteration?  then how would I filter if a value is more than the maximum cash?